# pass function to child component using react reorder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am stuck with passing function to child component of Reorder

Parent Component (some part of code)

```
import Reorder from 'react-reorder';
constructor() {
  super();
  this._bind(
    '_changeStatusReorder'
  );
  this.state = {
    status: true
  };
}

  _changeStatusReorder() {   //my function
    console.log('_changeStatusReorder');
    this.setState({
      status: false
    });
  }

return (
      <div className={styles.main}>
        <Reorder
          ...
          ...
          sharedProps={{changeStatus: this._changeStatusReorder}} //pass function to props
        />
      </div>
    );
```

and the child component

```
_handleMouseDown() {

    const {sharedProps: {changeStatus}} = this.props;
    console.log(sharedProps);  //try to see at console

    setTimeout(() => {

    },0);

  }
```

I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: sharedProps is not defined" in the console, so 
i don't know what i am wrong. i can't solve it.

Comment: I don't know React Reorder, but if `sharedProps` is a property of the child component, shouldn't you be accessing it via `this.props.sharedProps` not just by `sharedProps`?

Comment: What did you see at console.log(this.props) instead console.log(sharedProps);?

Comment: If i do like 'console.log(this.props.sharedProps);' i'll see an object, so i see  '_changeStatusReorder()' function in the object but i can't use that function. @Jayce444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `sharedProps={this._changeStatusReorder}`. And use in child component with `this.props.sharedProps()`

Comment: Oh, i got it but Can i use it as Object? @Andrew

Comment: Not sure i understand you. What are you trying to do? :)

Comment: I'd like to pass 2 function as props like 'sharedProps={{changeStatus: this._changeStatusReorder, another: this._ReturnStatus}}'

Comment: sure, then you will call them with this.props.sharedProps._changeStatusReorder()

Comment: And this is not understand for me `this._bind(
    '_changeStatusReorder'
  );` You can use `this._changeStatusReorder = this._changeStatusReorder.bind(this)` for bind.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew i got some idea now